# Добавить положительное число опыта

Tags: python, ооп

```
class Adventurer:
    """Adventurer class."""

    def __init__(self, name, class_type, power, experience=0):
        """Adventurer constructor.

        :param name: player name.
        :param class_type: character class.
        :param power: character power.
        :param experience: experience of character.
        """
        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        if power > 99:
            self.power = 10
        if class_type == "Druid" or class_type == "Wizard" or class_type == "Paladin":
            self.class_type = class_type
        else:
            self.class_type = "Fighter"
        self.experience = experience
        self.is_active = False

    def add_experience(self, exp):
        """Add experience to adventurer."""
       

    def add_power(self, power):
        """Add power to adventurer."""
        self.power += power

    def __repr__(self):
        """Representation of the adventurer."""
        return f"{self.name}, the {self.class_type}, Power: {self.power}, Experience: {self.experience}."
```

Adventurer — это простой класс, представляющий игрового персонажа или искателя приключений. Вы понятия не имеете, почему другим игрокам требуется так много времени, чтобы создать такой простой объект. Этот класс имеет четыре переменные экземпляра: имя, тип_класса, power и опыт. Конструктор Adventurer выглядит так: **init**(self, name: str, class_type: str, power: int, experience: int = 0)
name — это строка, которую не нужно как-либо проверять отдельно.
class_type может быть одним из четырех слов: Fighter, Druid, Wizard, Paladin. Если кто-то попытается создать Adventurer с другим class_type, таким как Мистик или Чернокнижник, он будет вынужден стать Воином. Ваш друг обещает, что эти ограничения важны для повествования.

При печати объекта Adventurer вы должны увидеть следующий текст: [name], [class_type], Power: [power], Experience: [experience].

Power - это целое число, которое может быть как положительным, так и отрицательным. начальное значение силы не должно быть больше 99. Если вы пытаетесь создать Adventurer с силой больше 99, начальное значение силы должно быть 10.
Experience также является целым числом, которое по умолчанию всегда равно 0. Experience не может быть отрицательным.

- `add_power(self, power: int)` — Добавляет указанную сумму к показателю силы Adventurer.
- `add_experience(self, exp: int)` — Добавляет указанную сумму к опыту Adventurer. Если опыт Adventurer больше 99, результат деления опыта на 10 прибавляется к его показателю силы (результат округляется в меньшую сторону). Затем опыт необходимо сбросить.

Comment: 1. Опишите подробнее - что значит "нет никакого эффекта"? Приведите конкретный код, как вы создаёте экземпляр класса, и по каким признакам видите, что эффекта нет. 2. В формуле вы путаете exp и self.experience и кроме этого не сбрасываете опыт. 3. В будущем не объединяйте две разных проблемы в один вопрос, каждую проблему нужно оформлять отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Изменил вопрос, дополнил его и очень надеюсь на помощь

Comment: в каком месте вызываются эти тесты и после каких манипуляций нам нужно самостоятельно догадаться? Так же не совсем ясна связь между заголовком и собственно проблемой.

Comment: Если бы я мог расписать задачу более подробно, я бы с удовольствием это сделал. Но это все условия и вся задача. На данный момент мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы опыт персонажа не был отрицательным и в случае если он больше 99, то добавлять результат деления на 10 к силе. и тем самым получать новое число опыта. Тесты предоставлены другим человеком и как-то их прокомментировать не могу.

Comment: Зачем вы весь код обсуждаемых функций убрали? Я хотел исправить и показать как надо, но писать с нуля мне что-то лениво. Верните код ))  И вообще на будущее - не меняйте код в исходном вопросе. Делайте все дополнения ниже основного вопроса. Иначе всё обсуждение вопроса становится непонятным тем, кто его потом будет читать.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if exp > 99:
            self.power + (exp // 10)
```

> Adventurer. Если опыт Adventurer больше 99, результат деления опыта на 10 прибавляется к его показателю силы (результат округляется в меньшую сторону). Затем опыт необходимо сбросить.

Ошибки:

1. Вы никуда не присваиваете результат произведённого вычисления
2. Вы не сбросили опыт после пересчёта силы

Но это объясняет только второй `assert`. Откуда отрицательный опыт в первом ассерте - непонятно, такого вроде бы не должно получиться при инициализации, и что нужно проверять опыт на неотрицательность в `add_experience` - такого в задании нет, а только так он мог получиться отрицательным. Хотя, в основной части задания всё же написано:

> Experience не может быть отрицательным.

Значит, всё-таки в `add_experience` нужно это проверять и это объясняет первый ассерт. Видимо, можно сделать это так же, как в конструкторе - то есть отрицательные числа приводить к нулю.

Comment: if exp < 0:
            self.experience = 0
вы это имеете ввиду?

Comment: Наверное всё-таки `if exp < 0: return` либо всё же `if self.expirience < 0: self.expirience = 0`, лучше бы этот момент как-то уточнить. Если экспа может уменьшаться в процессе игры, но не может падать меньше нуля - это один вариант. А если экспа не может уменьшаться при игре, то это другой вариант.

Comment: Если тесты можно гонять много раз, то просто попробуйте оба варианта, да посмотрите, какой тесты пройдёт.

Comment: Да, моя ошибка была в комментарии. С нулём понятно, спасибо! А вот дальше, if exp > 99:
            self.power + (exp // 10). Уже тоже думал, что результат никуда не выводится. Предположил, что будет правильнее     def add_experience(self, exp):
        """Add experience to adventurer."""
        self.experience += exp
        if exp > 99:
            result = math.floor(self.power + (exp // 10))
            return result
Но что то не так в этой формуле

Comment: Да просто знак равно добавьте self.power += (exp // 10)

Comment: Можете проверить ещё раз, всё ли я сделал верно в соотвествии с условиями задачи? (переделал вопрос) Уже не понимаю, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140797/discussion-between-koljumba-and-crazyelf).